# localdb по логину и паролю sql c# visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-localdb

У меня есть задача создать  новую базу данных localdb и подключиться к ней по логину паролю.

Это то что я пытался сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии окно появляется следующее окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь если я так же нажму ок он говорит что не верный логин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю я вообще куда то не туда думаю, подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону смотреть.

П.С. Это часть задания из курса по с# все это я так понял должно делаться в visual studio

Comment: а вы вообще подключиться можете к своей СУБД? Там хотя бы список таблиц поглядеть или запрос какой отправить. Просто со скринов выглядит, как будто у вас просто логин/пароль не подходит

Comment: @tym32167 Я новую создать пытался) нашел вот тут решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085957/how-to-add-username-and-password-in-sqllocaldb